# Illustrator type shader?

Tags: shaders

How do I make this shader (illustrator type artstyle but 3D)
[image]

[image]

HOW DO I IMPROVE THE SHADOW? MAKE IT COMPLETELY SMOOTH AND CRISP LIKE AN ILLUSTRATION?
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an emission shader / don't use a shader node:

[image]

To still get shadows, use a shader and pass it to "Shader to RGB" node (works only in Eevee). You may want to research "NPR rendering".

[image]

Comment: I added an image , i want to improve the shadows . how do i do it/?

Comment: @NewBlenderer define "improve".

Comment: my shadows are jagged. how can i make them like that in the example picture

Comment: @NewBlenderer try decreasing the radius of the point light to 0, and in render settings, disable soft shadows and increase their resolution…

Comment: Hi , the point light works as desired, but is it possible to have unlimited range like the SUN light?? The Pointlight has limited light spread.

Comment: @NewBlenderer I know I had problems with Sun light as well, there are some shadow improvements coming in "Eevee Next"…

Comment: Ok Thank you for the info. Exciting to see what's new in Eevee! :)